# How to span single line into multiple lines in VS code?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have the following code written in nodeJS..

```
async function GetSellerInfoByID({seller_user_id}) 
{    
    console.debug("Method : GetSellerInfoByID @user.service.js Calling...");
    await clientDB.connect();

    dataBaseData = await clientDB.query('select seller_profiles.user_id,seller_profiles.business_name,seller_profiles.status, buyer_profiles.first_name, images.image_url   buyer_profiles.last_name,  user_details.email from seller_profiles inner join user_details on user_details.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id left join address_books on address_books.id = seller_profiles.address_book_id left join phone_numbers on phone_numbers.id = seller_profiles.phone_number_id inner join buyer_profiles on  buyer_profiles.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id left join images on images.id = seller_profiles.business_logo_id where seller_profiles.user_id = $1', [seller_user_id,]);    

    //dataBaseData = await clientDB.query('select * from user_auth_validation where user_username=$1', [username]);     
    if(dataBaseData.rows.length > 0)
    {
        // dataBaseData.rows.forEach(element => {
            console.debug("data have.");
            //userID = element.user_id;
        // });
        // console.debug(dataBaseData.rows);
    }
    else
    {
        console.debug("Error in entered data, Please Check you Data Again.");
    }
            
    clientDB.end();
    return dataBaseData;
}
```

As you could see, my SQL query always wants to be in one line.
I wanted to be displayed as follows : (for readability)

```
dataBaseData = await clientDB.query('select  seller_profiles.user_id,seller_profiles.business_name,seller_profiles.status, buyer_profiles.first_name, images.image_url, buyer_profiles.last_name, user_details.email from seller_profiles 
inner join user_details on user_details.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id left join address_books on address_books.id = seller_profiles.address_book_id 
left join phone_numbers on phone_numbers.id = seller_profiles.phone_number_id 
inner join buyer_profiles on  buyer_profiles.user_id = seller_profiles.user_id 
left join images on images.id = seller_profiles.business_logo_id 
where seller_profiles.user_id = $1', [seller_user_id,]);
```

How could I do that in VS code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code formatter extension ([prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)) it will automatically reformat your code and make it readable, whenever you save your file.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you split it into substrings then concatenate as required.

Comment: Its not necessary as its part of the code.